# how to load loss function while loading tensorflow.keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to load saved tensorflow.keras model, on loading I'm getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Unknown loss function:cce_dice_loss
```

cce_dice_loss is from the library segmentation_models

please find the follwowing code for loss function

```
from segmentation_models.losses import cce_dice_loss

model2.compile(optimizer, cce_dice_loss, metrics=[iou_score])
```

please find the following code for saving and loading the model

```
model2.save("my_model",save_format='tf')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model', custom_objects={'convolutional_block': convolutional_block,'identity_block':identity_block,'global_flow':global_flow,'context_flow':context_flow,'sum_layer':sum_layer,'fsm':fsm,'agcn':agcn,'iou_score':iou_score,'focal_loss':focal_loss})
```

While loading the model I'm getting the error as I mentioned
please find the screen of the error

[image]

can anyone help me on resolving this issue.

Comment: Do you want to continue training or is the model just being loaded for prediction? You can use `load_model(..., compile=False)` if you don't need to continue training.

Comment: Actually  I need to continue training

Comment: @Leon Shams, can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong but it seems to be an issue with the loss function. If you are unable to figure out what is wrong you can always just create a separate model with randomly initialized weights and compile that. Then load in the pretrained model with `compile=False` and set your model weights to the weights of the pretrained model.

Comment: @LeonShams I'll try this and let you  know thank you

Comment: @LeonShams one doubt here I need to set the weights of pretrained model to current one right?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the code in your original trainer that generates the model to generate a new randomly initialized one.

Answer (score 0):

By saving as **HDF5** file, I was able to load like this:

```
import segmentation_models as sm
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score

print(iou_score.__name__)
>>> iou_score # Use this as custom_objects name

focal_loss = sm.losses.cce_dice_loss
print(focal_loss.__name__)
>>> categorical_crossentropy_plus_dice_loss # Use this as custom_objects name

model2.compile(optimizer, focal_loss, metrics = [iou_score])
model2.save('model.h5')

model = load_model('model.h5',
           custom_objects = {
           'categorical_crossentropy_plus_dice_loss' : focal_loss,
           'iou_score' : iou_score
           }
                  )
```